# sql left join not working

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I want to get total transfered items from table `inv_site_item` where `'item_id' in inv_sie_item = 'item_code'` in `inv_items`, I am getting packing also from packing table which works fine in this query only `inv_site_item` is giving problem.

error is: `Unknown column 'inv_site_item.site_id' in 'field list'`

```
$where .= " AND inv_items.item_code = $item_code";

$query = "SELECT inv_items.*,packing.name_en `packing_name`,"
    . " COUNT(inv_site_item.site_id) `transfer_out`, COUNT(inv_site_item.location_site_id) `transfer_in`  FROM inv_items"
            . " left join "
            . "inv_packing as packing on packing.id=inv_items.packing"
            . " left join "
            . "inv_site_item as transfer on transfer.item_id=inv_items.item_code"
    . " WHERE item_code !='' " . $where . "";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use your table alias `transfer` instead, So:

change from

```
inv_site_item.site_id
```

to

```
transfer.site_id
```

also with `inv_site_item.location_site_id` to be `transfer.location_site_id`

Comment: I just did it, it works in my query editor but not working in my browser, it gives error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE item_code !=''' at line 1

Comment: what is your $where equal ? can print query?

Comment: yes i mention in my question,  that is getting different things from different inputs for example   if item_code is given then $where will be $where .= " AND inv_items.item_code = $item_code"; similerly there is packing id and cost price

Comment: if (!empty($item_code)) {
            $where .= " AND inv_items.item_code = $item_code";
        } elseif (!empty($item_name)) {
            $where .= " AND inv_items.name_en LIKE '$item_name%'";
        } elseif (!empty($item_cost)) {
            $where .= " AND inv_items.current_cost = $item_cost";
        } elseif (!empty($item_packing)) {
            $where .= " AND inv_items.packing = $item_packing";
        }

Comment: @mohsin easily print $where and see the output

Answer (score 0):

For any query related errors you should always check to print the query if possible. Your "WHERE" clause is not getting populated correctly.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE item_code !=''' at line 1

This means that your query is giving error near your "WHERE" clause.

Print your $query variable to see the actual query that is built then you will be able to find the error and fix it.

```
<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($query); echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use your table alias `transfer` instead, So:

change from

```
inv_site_item.site_id
```

to

```
transfer.site_id
```

also with `inv_site_item.location_site_id` to be `transfer.location_site_id`

And also change `$where .= " AND inv_items.item_code = $item_code";` to

```
$where .= "inv_items.item_code = $item_code";
```

and

change query statement to

```
$query = "SELECT inv_items.*,packing.name_en `packing_name`,"
    . " COUNT(transfer.site_id) `transfer_out`, COUNT(transfer.location_site_id) `transfer_in`  FROM inv_items"
            . " left join "
            . "inv_packing as packing on packing.id=inv_items.packing"
            . " left join "
            . "inv_site_item as transfer on transfer.item_id=inv_items.item_code"
    . " WHERE " . $where . " AND item_code !=' '";
```

For let **not empty** clause come at last...